# How to make command+tab switch tabs like in PC in macOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

By default, in chrome for mac, the <kbd>command</kbd> key acts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> in windows. You use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to open a new tab and <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to close tabs. However, to switch between tabs you have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. This inconsistency is very uncomfortable, especially for people so used to Windows computers. I am aware that I can switch the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd> key functions in system preferences, but that doesn't help this situation.

I need all of the 3 functions I mentioned above use either <kbd>command</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key. Is this possible?

I think to switch "tabs" or "instances" within an application is a system shortcut, but I couldn't find where to set it.

Answer (score 0):

It's that way round because - in the same Windows-equivalent way -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   is the system-wide shortcut to switch applications.

The tabbing functionality was a very much later addition, within just the past few years.

Oddly, Chrome's own menu states that  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   should be the shortcut… but it doesn't work.

For most menu commands, you can change their defaults from System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts - but you cannot use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   as a replacement.